# change text align according to mobile device in Bootstrap 4

Tags: css, bootstrap-4

I have a horizontal label & text field. When I display in small device, It shows like bellow image..

[image]

I want to display **First Name** in left align in small devices. I have used bellow code

```
 <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-4 text-right">
        <label for="firstname" class="control-label text-right">First Name :</label>
     </div>
      <div class="col-sm-6">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter Your First Name"  />                 
      </div>
```

Please help me..

Comment: You can see Documentation of Bootstrap https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.3/utilities/text/#text-alignment

Answer (score 3):

Using only bootstrap

---

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-4 text-md-right text-sm-left" >
        <label for="firstname" class="control-label">First Name :</label>
     </div>
      <div class="col-sm-6">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter Your First Name"  />                 
      </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

There is nothing built into bootstrap for this, but some simple css could fix it. Something like this should work.

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-4 text-right mob-text-left">
        <label for="firstname" class="control-label text-right">First Name :</label>
     </div>
      <div class="col-sm-6">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter Your First Name"  />                 
      </div>



@media (max-width: 768px) {
      .mob-text-left {
              text-align: left;
       } 
    }
```